# Weld-SE not logging with log4j2

Tags: log4j2, weld-se

Im using weld-se and log4j2 for logger. But I cannot get anything from Weld. Other logging works fine.

Libraries:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

log4j2.xml

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <logger name="org.jboss.weld.level" level="debug"/>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the SLF4J implementation for Log4j 2:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

JBoss Weld use the class [`org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java) for find a logging provider. If you see the [code](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logging/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logging/LoggerProviders.java) of this class, you will see that looks for a system property, **`org.jboss.logging.provider`**.

You can added to jvm arguments or you can emulate it. e.g.:

```java
public class App {

    static {
        System.setProperty("org.jboss.logging.provider", "slf4j");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        // Do something
        weld.shutdown();
    }

}
```